# при несоблюдении условий, вопрос не повторяется, не понимаю, как исправить

Tags: python

```
x=['1. Я суетлив и неусидчив.',
'2. Я несдержан и вспыльчив.',
'3. Я нетерпелив.',
'4. Я резок и прямолинеен в общении.',
'5. Я часто являюсь инициатором всевозможных мероприятий.']
i=0
j=0
for j in x:
    response=""
    n=0
    while True:
        response=input(x[n],\n)
        if response.lower() not in ("да","нет"):
            print("Отвечайте только да или нет")
        elif response.lower()=="да":
            i+=1
        elif response.lower()=="нет":
            i+=0
        n+=1
print(i)
```

---

Comment: Вы запускаете именно этот код, который в вопросе привели? А то он у вас вообще не должен запускаться из-за \n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, `n+=1` должно выполняться только если выбрано `да` или `нет`. У вас же оно выполняется в любом случае.

Во-вторых, даже если устранить эту проблему, код не будет нормально работать. Так как у вас не предусмотрено условие выхода из цикла. `while True` будет работать бесконечно. Его нужно заменить например на `while n<5`.

В-третьих, у вас зачем-то вложены друг в друга два цикла, каждый из которых итерируется по `x`. Если вы оставите это как есть, то ваш скрипт вам пять раз задаст весь набор вопросов.

Нужно оставить либо только внешний цикл, либо только внутренний.

Comment: спасибо большое, код заработал =) x=['1. Я суетлив и неусидчив.',
'2. Я несдержан и вспыльчив.',
'3. Я нетерпелив.',
'4. Я резок и прямолинеен в общении.',
'5. Я часто являюсь инициатором всевозможных мероприятий.']
i=0
response=""
n=0
while n<5:
    response=input(x[n])
    if response.lower() not in ("да","нет"):
        print("Отвечайте только да или нет")
    elif response.lower()=="да":
        i+=1
        n+=1
    elif response.lower()=="нет":
        i+=0
        n+=1
print(i)